# C# BackgroundWorker Completed Called Way Before Completion

Tags: c#, forms, session, outlook, backgroundworker

I have been trying to work out why my background worker is 'finishing' its work when there is still a lot for it to do. I am actually in the process of refactoring the code for this app, so it did work in the past, but now I am unable to figure out what has gone wrong.

Specifically, the app should open Outlook and then perform a few checks. However, the background worker exits straight after Outlook is opened for no apparent reason (as you will se below there is still plenty of processing to be done).

This appears to be happening early on in the `Start()` method, directly after calling `Process.Start()` on Outlook.exe.

The code runs in this order:

**`calling the background worker - this was the user's choice from a radio set`**

```
....
        else if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Please wait while your session restarts";
            pageControl1.SelectedIndex = 10;

            backgroundReset.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

**`The do-work method`**

```
    public void backgroundReset_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundReset.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        Session.Reset();
    }
```

**`the reset session method starts by killing the current session ...`**

```
    public static void Reset()
    {
        KillSession();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        Start();

        // THE BACKGROUNDWORKER EXITS BEFORE HERE!

        if (IsLoggedIn() == false)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // Make sure Lync is open before finishing the process ...
            var j = 0;

            GetSession(Init.servers);

            j = 0;
            var checker = false;

            checker = ProcessHandler.CheckRunning("lync.exe");

            while (checker == false)
            {
                if (j == 100)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                checker = ProcessHandler.CheckRunning("lync.exe");
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see from the comment, the backgroundworder is calling RunWorkerCompleted way before the Reset() method has finished executing.

Below are the other methods called (kill, logoff, start):

**`KillSession logs the session of and then makes sure it is logged off`**

```
    private static void KillSession()
    {
        if (sessionId != null)
        {
            LogOff();

            for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
            {
                if (IsLoggedIn() == true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**`LogOff sends a Cmd command to log off the current session`**

```
    public static void LogOff()
    {
        string strCmdIn = "/C LOGOFF " + sessionId + " /SERVER:" + serverName;
        Cmd.Exec(strCmdIn);
    }
```

**`Start() Simply opens Outlook, causing a Citrix session to also start. The app is definitely launching Outlook, but after that it doesn't reach either of the for statements - the BackgroundWorker just exits.`**

```
    public static void Start()
    {
        Process.Start(appDataCitrix + "Outlook.exe");

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {

            if (IsLoggedIn2() == false)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (IsLoggedIn2() == false)
        {
            Process.Start(appDataCitrix + "Outlook.exe");

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (IsLoggedIn2() == false)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? It is driving me crazy!

Many thanks

**Update**

**`The RunWorkerCompleted Method:`**
`As far as my understanding goes, this has no baring on when the process will finish.`

```
    public void backgroundReset_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session.IsLoggedIn())
        {
            btnFailFinish.Visible = true;
            label10.Text = Session.serverName;
            pageControl1.SelectedIndex = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            pageControl1.SelectedIndex = 10;
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;

            textBox1.Text = "Double-click Outlook on your desktop to launch a new session.";
            textBox15.Text = "Once you have done this please click Finish.";
            pictureBox9.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably exiting due to an error. Step through with debugger and see where it breaks and why

Comment: Musefan I have tried this - the debugger fails me after Process.Start(Outlook). At this point, the app hangs, but there is no sign of any error message or exception - totally useless! I have never seen this on VS before so I suspect I may be missing something ...

Comment: "...As you can see from the comment...": Comments don't run code, and since there's also no code provided for RunWorkerCompleted handler, I can't say if it's called to early (which, most likely, it isn't). As others have said: Most likely, Process.Start(appDataCitrix + "Outlook.exe") crashes. Find out why. And, while being on a pedantic spree: "IsLoggedIn2()". Really?

Comment: Thanks for the input Willem. I added the RunWorkerCompleted method as you suggested, but I'm not sure if it is helpful. Also, why are you assuming that a isloggedin2 isn't helpful to me? They are 2 different methods that do 2 different things. One more thing - The comment is true, so your first statement is just so pointless. The code does stop before the comment ...

Comment: There was a pedantry warning included, but anyway: Which one does what? Does IsLoggedIn2() check whether your logged into "Frob", or does "IsLoggedIn1()" take care of that? Leaving aside of course, that IsLoggedInEx(), and compatriots IsLoggedInEx2() and IsUserLoggedIn(), might also take care of that. Being explicit in naming stuff is not harmful, does not make code run slower, nor is it less cool.

Comment: IsLoggedIn() checks whether the user is logged in to the session which it has credentials saved for, IsLoggedIn2() checks whether the user is logged in in any capacity. I know this isn't ideal but I am a long way from the app being finished, and I am refactoring it from some pretty horrific code. Appreciate the suggestions but I am much more concerned with my BackgroundWorker at the moment

Comment: Hence the pedantry warning. Back to business: Process.Start(appDataCitrix + "Outlook.exe") crashes. Find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because of an exception being thrown from within the `start` method.

You may either add a try / catch block all around this method and handle the error from within the catch, or check in the RunWorkerCompleted method if an exception occurred :

```
    private void RunWorkerCompleted (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            // handle your exception here
        }
    }
```